# Installing opencv on Windows 10 with python 3.6 and anaconda 3.6

Tags: python, opencv, anaconda

How to install opencv with python 3.6 and anaconda 3.6?

I tried `conda install -c https://conda.binstar.org/menpo opencv3`

but i get the following error:

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - opencv3 -> python 2.7*
  - python 3.6*
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

I am using Windows 10 64-bit, with python 3.6, and anaconda 3.6 installed.

Is it even available for python3.6 at the moment or should i rollback my python version to 3.5.*?

Comment: Check [THIS LINK](https://www.scivision.co/anaconda-python-opencv3/)

Comment: ye, i checked but still could not install it... so i ended up downgrading python version to 3.5.3 using conda and then was able to install it..

Comment: @ŽeljkoKrnjić see answer for installing cv2 to Python 3.6 on Win64.

Answer (score 44):

search **anaconda prompt**
open and run the **command**.

```
> pip install opencv-python
```

this single command help's you to install opencv easily.
you can take help from the video link below.
[video link](https://youtu.be/O1vRXr_GD18)

Answer (score 36):

From menpo [file page](https://anaconda.org/menpo/opencv3/files), it shows that the OpenCV 3.2 binary there are only for Python 2.7/3.4/3.5 and on **linux-64** platform

[image]

You may go to the [this](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#opencv) site to get the exact version you need.

[image: Available OpenCV3.2 binary for Windows]

- `opencv_python‑3.2.0‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl` is the basic one.
- `opencv_python‑3.2.0+contrib‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl` is the one
  with opencv-contrib modules such as the `text` module for binding to tesseract OCR engine and many others.

Both binary are for OpenCV 3.2 with Python 3.6 binding for Windows 64-bit. To install it, 1) download the binary to local drive, 2) open your Anaconda command prompt and 3) type the command below in the directory the binary locates.

```
pip install opencv_python‑3.2.0+contrib‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl
```

Hope this help.

[image]

**Update on 2018-02-22:**

`OpenCV 3.4.0` wheel files are now available in the [unofficial site](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#opencv) and replaced `OpenCV 3.3.0`

**Update on 2019-01-30:**

`OpenCV 4.0.1` wheel files are now available in the [unofficial site](https://anaconda.org/menpo/opencv3/files) with `CPython 3.5/3.6/3.7` support.

Comment: An update. OpenCV 3.3 is now available in [this](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#opencv) site for Python 3.x.

Comment: Hi - I'm starting playing around with OpenCV and this helped me with the setup. Some more pitfalls I had:

* downloaded opencv_python‑3.3.1‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl from your page

* run Anaconda Prompt as Admin

* then it still could not load..so I also installed numpy‑1.13.3+mkl‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl

* then finally everything worked

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 13):

I managed to get it working by doing the following:

1. Download and install python3.6 from official python site
   https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-360/
2. Download and install Anaconda 4.4.0 from the official anaconda site
   https://www.continuum.io/downloads
3. Open command line and run:
   **pip install opencv-python**
4. Open command line and run:
   **pip install opencv-contrib-python**

   I am using Windows 10 and it worked for me.

Answer (score 8):

It's pretty simple..

Install Anaconda 3.6. Check anaconda is added to System Variable Path.

Open CMD and type `conda install -c conda-forge opencv`. 
This will install latest OpenCV version available (3.6).

Open IDE editor and try `import cv2`. 
It will probably don't work...don't worry.

You have to add `cv2` command to editor.

**For Eclipse (with PyDev):**

Create firs a project and then do the following:

[image: Eclipse tutorial]

**For PyCharm:**

*cv2* module probably won't work. Go to the `Anaconda folder/Lib/site-packages/cv2` and copy the file `cv2.cp36-win_amd64.pyd` to the site-packages folder. Rename it `cv2.pyd`

[image: Example2]

Now try to write a command... `cv2.imread()`. If auto-completition don't work, try `cv2.cv2.imread()`.
This will work for sure.

Comment: This works perfectly, definitively should be higher!

Answer (score 7):

I am using **Python 3.6.2** and **Anaconda 4.3.23** (It should also work with your case).

I did the following:

- Download the Numpy version corresponding to your Python installation from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy). In my case, I’ve used *numpy-1.13.1+mkl-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl*
- Download the OpenCV version corresponding to your Python installation from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#opencv). In my case, I’ve used *opencv_python-3.3.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl*
- Now go to the folder where you downloaded these files and run the following:

  pip install numpy-1.13.1+mkl-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl

  pip install opencv_python-3.3.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl

Note the Successfully installed … message after each command.

At this point, you should be able to play with OpenCV and Python. Let’s try a small test first. Start the *Python interpreter* or *Jupyter Notebook* and write:

```
import cv2 
print(cv2.__version__)
```

If everything was correctly installed, you should see the version number of your OpenCV install, in my case this was 3.3.0.

Answer (score 5):

I see you found a solution but this may be helpful for others. The package is not available for Python 3.6. You can check this by going to that package channel on anaconda.org and selecting the files tab. You will see the package tarballs with the Python version listed as py27, py34, py35,etc. This is a good way to check for Python versions of a specific package.

You can also run the following to see the package versions and Python versions available for your OS from the Anaconda channel:

```
conda search <package_name>
```

Or to search a particular channel and package you can do this:

```
conda search -c <channel_name> <package_name>
```

Comment: To add to my answer in a case where a package is not available for your Python version you can use anaconda environments to setup an environment with any python versions you need.

Answer (score 3):

As of March 2018, OpenCV 3.4 can be installed directly from conda-forge or anaconda in Windows/OSX/Linux for Python 3.6

```
conda install -c conda-forge opencv
```

or

```
conda install -c anaconda opencv
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Using:

`conda install -c conda-forge opencv`

worked for me

Answer (score 2):

If you have installed anaconda then you should uninstall it, then try

```
pip install opencv_python‑3.2.0+contrib‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl
```

It worked for me.
Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

I am using python 3.6 and the following worked for me:

- Download and install opencv (Win pack) on your computer from the official website: 
  https://opencv.org/releases.html (I took version 3.4.2)
- Go to the website of Christoph Gohlke and download the wheel file corresponding to your system. (I took opencv_python-3.4.2-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl)
- As mentioned on the website of Christoph Gohlke, make sure you installed 'numpy1.14' & 'mkl' package. Also make sure you use pip with version 9 or newer.
- Start the 'Anaconda Prompt'
- Change the directory in the 'Anaconda Prompt' to the folder where you downloaded the wheel file from Gohlke's website (via the MS-DOS command 'cd').
- In the 'Anaconda Prompt' type 'pip install opencv_python-3.4.2-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl') (change the name of the wheel file accordingly).

When starting spyder, test your installation as follows:

```
import cv2
print(cv2.__version__)
```

If the version is printed in the console (in my case 3.4.2), your installation was successful.

IMPORTANT REMARK:
If you created a dedicated environment within Anaconda (in my case 'py36'), make sure you installed spyder for this dedicated environment ('conda install spyder'). If not, your installation of opencv will not be recognised within the environment you are working in. Maybe this is obvious and straightforward but in my case I struggled to find this solution.

Answer (score 0):

First Download [Anaconda Python 3.6](https://www.anaconda.com/download/)  from official site. After installing anaconda, simply open command prompt and type following statement and press enter of course -

```
conda install -c conda-forge opencv
```

It may take some time. After the completion, check your conda packages by typing `conda list` - opencv should be there.

However, Before proceed to install `opencv`, you can check whether `opencv` for `python 3.6` is available or not. We can check it by typing `conda info opencv` in command prompt and press enter of course, you'll see following -

```
opencv 3.3.1 py36h20b85fd_1
---------------------------
file name   : opencv-3.3.1-py36h20b85fd_1.tar.bz2
name        : opencv
version     : 3.3.1
build string: py36h20b85fd_1
build number: 1
channel     : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
size        : 96.7 MB
arch        : None
constrains  : ()
license     : BSD 3-clause
license_family: BSD
md5         : e65c68524073445511ace8ade7ae3641
platform    : None
subdir      : win-64
timestamp   : 1512689066576
url         : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/opencv-3.3.1-py36h20b85fd_1.tar.bz2
dependencies:
    jpeg >=9b,<10a
    libpng >=1.6.32,<1.7.0a0
    libtiff >=4.0.9,<5.0a0
    numpy >=1.11.3,<2.0a0
    python >=3.6,<3.7.0a0
    vc 14.*
    zlib >=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0
```

By this we can also get ensure that `opencv 3.3.1 py36h20b85fd_1` is available. And this is available for `python 3.6`

Answer (score 0):

I think this way is straight forward. Just install anaconda from official page and follow the image.

[image: i think this way is straight forward. just install anaconda from official page. and follow the image.]

Answer (score 0):

Using [Anaconda3](https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/)'s package manager directly will be more reliable and cross-platform:

```
conda install opencv
```