# How to fix Python version error when trying to download opencv3?

Tags: python, opencv, download, opencv3.1

I have Anaconda installed and I used the following command in the Command Prompt:

```
conda install -c menpo opencv3
```

Which returned this error:

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
- opencv3 -> python 2.7*
- python 3.6*
Use "conda info<package> to see the dependencies for each package.
```

I attempted to find a solution [here](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/2448) without success. My python version on Anaconda is 3.6. Why does it return this error, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

openCV doesn't currently support Python 3.6. You need to use a different version of Python.

This page may be of help: [installing-opencv-on-windows-10-with-python-3-6-and-anaconda-3-6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42994813/installing-opencv-on-windows-10-with-python-3-6-and-anaconda-3-6).

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you need to download Python 2 to be able to use this. It's more than fine to have more than 1 version of python installed on your machine. But I wouldn't suggest more than one version of 3 and more than one version of 2, because then it can get confusing.