# After a clean install of OpenCV via pip it throws an ImportError: DLL load failed

Tags: python, opencv, dll, ffmpeg, pip

After installing OpenCV via pip on Windows 10 with:

```
pip install opencv-python
```

I can not import the module. When executing the command:

```
import cv2
```

I get the error:

> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cv2__init__.py",
>   line 7, in 
>       from . import cv2
>
> ImportError: DLL load failed:...

If I look into the file throwing the code, it looks like the following:

```
import sys
import os

# FFMPEG dll is not found on Windows without this
os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

from . import cv2
sys.modules['cv2'] = cv2
```

So I guess it is ffmpeg which is missing. Thus I installed ffmpeg like described here: http://www.wikihow.com/Install-FFmpeg-on-Windows

Thus, ffmpeg is in my path. However, the error message still occurs. I also tried to install the ffmpeg via pip with

```
pip install ffmpeg-normalize
```

But this did not help either.

Comment: Check answers in this [dll-load-failed-error-when-importing-cv2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43184887/dll-load-failed-error-when-importing-cv2/43190144#43190144) and this [installing-opencv-on-windows-10-with-python-3-6-and-anaconda-3-6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42994813/installing-opencv-on-windows-10-with-python-3-6-and-anaconda-3-6/43022332#43022332). They might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `opencv-python` Windows packages ship with FFmpeg by default. You can have a look at `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cv2` and you should find FFmpeg DLL there. You don't have to install it separately.

The real problem lies most probably in Anaconda because they are not shipping `python3.dll` with their distribution. This is required by PEP 384. Related Anaconda issue is here: https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/1394

To fix this, you will have to copy `python3.dll` from a CPython installer package and place it to PATH. The CPython version must match your Anaconda version. Easiest way is to copy the file to some place which is already in PATH. This could be for example `C:\Anaconda3` if that's where your Anaconda installation is located.

If the above does not work, make sure that you have  Visual C++ redistributable 2015 installed: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145