# How can I install opencv3 for python3 with conda?

Tags: python, macos, opencv, anaconda, conda

I tried to install opencv3 with conda on my mac. Somehow opencv seems to be installed for python2.7. Actually I removed that with

```
brew uninstall opencv
```

heres the error for

```
conda install -c menpo opencv3

Fetching package metadata .............
Solving package specifications: .

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - opencv3 -> python 2.7*
  - python 3.6*
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing opencv on Windows 10 with python 3.6 and anaconda 3.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42994813/installing-opencv-on-windows-10-with-python-3-6-and-anaconda-3-6)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I only needed the python version of opencv

```
pip install opencv-python
```

worked fine. Thanks to @Max