# OpenCV import cv2 not recognised

Tags: python, opencv

Alright, so I am trying to work with Python/OpenCV to make a program for face detection, but I keep having this yellow underline that appears underneath the "cv2"

```
import cv2
```

I've tried putting the installed OpenCV file from online into the same folder as my program, but it still didn't work

Take a look at the yellow underline under "cv2" here:

[image: IDE]

Comment: Take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42994813/installing-opencv-on-windows-10-with-python-3-6-and-anaconda-3-6/45350358#45350358[here].

Answer (score -1):

install opencv library for python using

> pip install opencv-python

command

Ref:https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/

Comment: It's not about installing opencv; as you can see, when opencv functions are being used, they're not marked/underlined in red (cv2.imread for example).